# Deserialize Protobuf kafka messages with Flink

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, protocol-buffers, apache-flink, confluent-schema-registry

I am trying to read and print Protobuf message from Kafka using Apache Flink.

I followed the official docs with no success: https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/datastream/fault-tolerance/serialization/third_party_serializers/

The Flink consumer code is:

```
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.createLocalEnvironmentWithWebUI()
    env.enableCheckpointing(5000)
    env.getCheckpointConfig.setCheckpointingMode(CheckpointingMode.EXACTLY_ONCE)
    env.getCheckpointConfig.setCheckpointStorage(s"$targetPath/checkpoints")
    env.getConfig.registerTypeWithKryoSerializer(classOf[User], classOf[ProtobufSerializer])

    val source = KafkaSource.builder[User]
      .setBootstrapServers(brokers)
      .setTopics(topic)
      .setGroupId(consumerGroupId)
      .setValueOnlyDeserializer(new ProtoDeserializer())
      .setStartingOffsets(OffsetsInitializer.earliest)
      .build

    val stream = env.fromSource(source, WatermarkStrategy.noWatermarks[User], kafkaTableName)
    stream.print()
    env.execute()
  }
```

The deserializer code is:

```
class ProtoDeserializer extends DeserializationSchema[User] {

  override def getProducedType: TypeInformation[User] = null

  override def deserialize(message: Array[Byte]): User = User.parseFrom(message)

  override def isEndOfStream(nextElement: User): Boolean = false
}
```

I get the following error when the streamer is executed:

```
Protocol message contained an invalid tag (zero).
```

It's important to mention that I manage to read and deserialize the messages successfully using the [confluent protobuf consumer](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python/blob/master/examples/protobuf_consumer.py) so it seems that the messages are not corrupted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The confluent protobuf serializer doesn't produce content that can be directly deserialized by other deserializers. [The format is described in confluent's documentation](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/serdes-develop/index.html#wire-format): it starts with a magic byte (that is always zero), followed by a four byte schema ID. The protobuf payload follows, starting with byte 5.

The `getProducedType` method should return appropriate `TypeInformation`, in this case `TypeInformation.of(User.class)`. Without this you may run into problems at runtime.

Deserializers used with `KafkaSource` don't need to implement `isEndOfStream`, but it won't hurt anything.

Comment: Thanks David, very helpful! Do you have any recommendation how to skip the first 5 bytes, rather than change the `deserialize` method to be `User.parseFrom(message.slice(6, message.length))`?

Comment: No, I don't have a better idea. Wish I did.